# assignment operator by value not compiling with explicit copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I want to understand what correct parameter types should be used in an explicit copy constructor(s).

As defined below, using "explicit", the assignment code will not compile. The assignment lines in main generate the error: 'No matching constructor for initialisation of CCat'

Removal of "explicit" from the first copy constructor fixes the problem, but I don't understand why.

The compiler is obviously doing some subtle implicit casting?

```
class CCat : public CAnimal
{
public:
    explicit CCat( string name, uint noLegs, bool fur, bool domestic, string breed );

    explicit CCat( const CCat& oldCat ) : CAnimal( oldCat )
    {
        std::cout << "\nCCat::CCat( const CCat& oldCat ) \n";
    }
    explicit CCat( CCat& oldCat ) : CAnimal( oldCat )
    {
        std::cout << "\nexplicit CCat::CCat( CCat& oldCat ) \n";
    }
    ~CCat();

    CCat& operator =( CCat oldCat ){
        //.. do assignment stuff
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    CCat *cat1 = new CCat( string("Wiggy"),  4, true, true, string("Tabby") );
    CCat *cat2 = new CCat( string("Tibles"),  4, true, true, string("Tom") );

    CCat tempCat( *cat1 );
    CCat tempCat2( *cat2 );
    std::cout << "CCat tempCat2( *cat2 );\n";

    const CCat& tempCat3 = *cat2;

    tempCat = tempCat3;    // will not compile without explicit removed from first C/Constr
    tempCat = CCat(*cat2); // will not compile without explicit removed from first C/Constr
    tempCat = tempCat2;    // will not compile without explicit removed from first C/Constr
    return 0;
}
```

The assignment operator (passing by value) forces the use of a copy constructor, however a perfect match cannot be found when explicit is used. So when explicit is removed what conversions is the compiler performing and how can I write a matching copy constructor?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking, you appear to have already found the problem...

Comment: Copy constructors should not be explicit.

Comment: Is your assignment operator doing copy-and-swap or something similar? Otherwise it would take const reference.

Comment: @T.C. why should Copy constructors not be explicit, what is the rational?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment

```
tempCat = tempCat3
```

is investigated by overload resolution and rewritten as

```
tempCat.operator=(tempCat3)
```

Overload resolution now looks for a matching member function to call. It finds your copy assignment operator:

```
CCat& operator=( CCat oldCat )
```

The parameter `oldCat` has to be initialized with the argument, `tempCat3`. The correct term is actually *copy-initialization*.

> The initialization that occurs in the form
>
> ```
> T x = b;
> ```
>
> as well as in argument passing, […] is *called copy-initialization*.

copy-initialization only works with non-explicit constructors:

> For copy-initialization, the candidate functions are all the
>   converting constructors (12.3.1) of that class.

(also called converting constructors):

> A constructor declared without the function-specifier `explicit`
>   specifies a conversion from the types of its parameters to the type of
>   its class. Such a constructor is called a *converting constructor*.

So if you declare your copy constructor with the `const`-reference parameter as `explicit`, it isn't a converting constructor, copy-initialization doesn't work and the parameter cannot be initialized with the argument - that is also what the compiler tells us, no matching constructor was found.
 The same applies to the other lines in `main`.

If `explicit` is removed the initialization works just fine.

Comment: You have definately increased my knowledge today. Where can I look to get further general info on the steps the compiler takes when passing source code, eg. as you have explained above? Also I don't understand why "copy-initialization only works with non-explicit constructors" am I missing something?